# Convert a AWS EC2 URL to WMS URL

Tags: qgis, wms, basemap, tile-server, amazon-web-services

I have built my tile server on AWS EC2 instance and want to use it as a base map in QGIS. 
When I try to add it as a WMS layer on QGIS, I get an error saying `The server you are trying to connect to does not seem to be a WMS server. Please check the URL.`

Do I need to convert my AWS url to a WMS URL?
Are there any tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Are you blocked by your own AWS IP? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938778/access-geoserver-from-amazon-e2c-from-internet I think you need Geoserver to publish the WMS

Comment: A WMS isn't a tile server.  Is your AWS tile server a WMS? if not, trying to get QGIS to connect to as if it were is going to cause you problems.   Can you give more information about the requests that generate maps or map tiles, in your question, then it might be possible to give an answer that enables you to connect to it